# Is there any difference between -exec cmd {} and xargs -I?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find, xargs

Normally, `xargs` bundles everything together, but when used with the `-I` flag it seems to put evaluate everything as a single line. Does this mean it loses its speed advantage? Also if the `-exec cmd {}` + syntax is used does that mean it will perform better than `xargs -I`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes".

`xargs -I{} cmd` allows multiple occurrences of the specified replacement string, but will only supply one input item per execution of `cmd`, meaning in the following example, `echo` will be invoked three times:

```
$ mkdir t
$ cd t
$ touch foo bar baz

$ find . -type f | xargs -I{} echo {} {}
./bar ./bar
./baz ./baz
./foo ./foo
```

Note that if you don't need to specify each input item more than once per command line, then `find -exec cmd {} +` is roughly equivalent to `find | xargs` (without `-I`), except it handles filenames with whitespace by default (to handle embedded whitespace correctly with the latter, use `find -print0 | xargs -0`).

`find -exec cmd {} +` will pass multiple input items to `cmd`, but only one occurrence of the replacement string (`{}`) is allowed. This is also the default behavior of `xargs` without `-I`. In the following example, `echo` is only invoked once for each set of arguments (for large input sets, both approaches will split the input into chunks such that each generated command line is shorter than `PATH_MAX`, meaning `cmd` could be invoked multiple times, but far fewer than once per input item):

```
$ find . -type f -exec echo {} +
./bar ./baz ./foo

$ find . -type f | xargs echo
./bar ./baz ./foo
```